# Blank entry along with valid entry

Tags: php

I am working on a project that can be used to book events the data is stored in a database, everything else works fine, but when I insert a new entry manually through web interface, the event is entered but it adds another event without any dates, times or event name or location, i am new to this and cant seem to figure it out, can someone assist me?

here is the code....................

```
<?php
 $target = "upload/"; 
 $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']); 


 $name=$_POST['eventname']; 
 $description=$_POST['eventdescription'];
 $edate=$_POST['eventdate'];
 $etime=$_POST['eventtime'];
 $location=$_POST['eventlocation'];
 $speaker=$_POST['eventspeaker'];
 $pic=($_FILES['photo']['name']);
 $n="upload/$pic"; 
 $duration=$_POST['eventduration'];
 $created=$_POST['createdby'];

 mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "password") or die(mysql_error()) ; 
 mysql_select_db("event") or die(mysql_error()) ; 


 mysql_query("INSERT INTO `events` (eventname, eventdescription, eventdate, eventtime,    eventlocation, eventspeaker, speakerphoto, eventduration, createdby) VALUES ('$name', '$description', '$edate', '$etime', '$location', '$speaker', '$n', '$duration', '$created')") ; 



 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target)) 

  } 
 else {


 ?>
```

Here is the create table and inserts to my database.

```
<?
$query[5] = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `events` (
```

`eventsID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `eventname` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `eventdescription` tinytext,
  `eventdate` date NOT NULL,
  `eventlocation` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `eventspeaker` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `speakerphoto` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `eventduration` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `createdby` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `eventtime` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`eventsID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `eventsID` (`eventsID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 PACK_KEYS=0 AUTO_INCREMENT=4";

insert code:

```
$query[4] = "INSERT INTO `attendees` (`attID`, `username`, `lastname`, `firstname`,    `age`, `postaladdress`, `Event`, `attendance`, `comments`) VALUES
```

Comment: This code seems fine, error is obviously somewhere else

Comment: What mechanism is submitting the form? Maybe its being called twice.

Comment: 1. thing you should do is to escape the database input. Another thing - could you show us an example of $_POST data and your database type-structure? I thing that possible problem could be that you are storing different data types than what belongs to your table columns. (e.g. inserting wrong formated date, inserting string into an integer,...)

Comment: I just added the table structure and the inputs.

Comment: Problem solved, it had to do with the version of php and apache i was running, had to get apache 2.2.4 and php 5.4.1 thanks for the help everyone...